# how to validation credit card in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

how to validate credit card number... less then 16, month 1 to 12, ? please help.

see below code and image

```
  <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='paymentrow.number ' name='number'></td>
 <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='paymentrow.exp_month ' name='exp_month'></td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='paymentrow.number ' name='number' ng-pattern="/^\d{1,16}$/"></td>

<td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='paymentrow.exp_month ' name='exp_month' ng-pattern="/[1-9]|1[012]/"></td>

<td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='paymentrow.exp_year ' name='exp_year' min="2016" max="2050"></td>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: year   ?? please one more

Comment: Use type ``type = 'text'`` instead of ``number`` for both card no and exp_month input.